# two strings of integers. Check if the second one is substring

Tags: c, string, substring

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int x[100], y[100], i, j, dim1, dim2, subsir=0;
  scanf("%d", &dim1);
  for(i=0; i<dim1; i++)
  {
      scanf("%d", &x[i]);
  }
  scanf("%d", &dim2);
  for(j=0; j<dim2; j++)
  {
      scanf("%d", &y[j]);
  }
  if(dim1<dim2)
  {
      printf("no");
      return 0;
  }
  for(i=0; i<dim1; i++)
    for(j=0; j<dim2; j++)
        {
        if(x[i]==y[j])
            subsir=1;
        }


  if(subsir==1)
  {
      printf("yes");
  }
  else
  {
      printf("no");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Consider two strings of integers. Check if the second string is a substring of the first in C.(the substring consists of consecutive elements of the first string)

Comment: You must ask a question. There's no question here.

Comment: The question is " how to solve it?" . i need an idea

Comment: The function you want is `strstr` in `<string.h>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is quite general, while questions on here are usually a bit more specific. What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code? What is a simpler problem that you _can_ solve?

Comment: @my_name If you need to implement a function that does what you described, you have to show some of your code first. Then, we can help you finding errors/bugs in your code, in case it doesn't work.

Comment: isn't the function strstr used only for strings of characters?

Comment: @my_name yes, but that mentioned strings and substrings, I thought you meant a string of characters that would evaluate to true with `isdigit`, that's why you need to post some of your code so we know more about what you are asking.

Comment: @my_name For "string of integers" you mean something like this: `char s[] = "123456";` or do you mean this: `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`?

Comment: @LucaPolito this is my code, but i think that at the if part is the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your goal with a brute force approach, trying every position from `0` to `dim1 - dim2`.

Here is a modified version with error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x[100], y[100], i, j, dim1, dim2;

    if (scanf("%d", &dim1) != 1 || dim1 > 100)
        return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < dim1; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &x[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    if (scanf("%d", &dim2) != 1 || dim2 > 100)
        return 1;

    /* no need to read second array if larger */
    if (dim1 < dim2) {
        printf("no\n");
        return 0;
    }
    for (j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &y[j]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    /* trying every possible sub-array start in array `x` */
    for (i = 0; i <= dim1 - dim2; i++) {
        /* compare all entries */
        for (j = 0; j < dim2; j++) {
            if (x[i + j] != y[j])
                break;
        }
        /* if above loop completed, we have a match */
        if (j == dim2) {
           printf("yes\n");
           return 0;
        }
    }
    printf("no\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible implementation, based on your approach:

```c
// this function will return `1` in case `arr2` is contained inside `arr1`, otherwise `0`
int is_subarr(int arr1[], size_t arr1_len, int arr2[], size_t arr2_len) {
  // as you already did, we first check that arr1's len is not smaller than arr2's
  if (arr1_len < arr2_len) {
    return 0;
  }

  // useful check: in many implementations, when `arr2` is empty, they return true
  if (arr2_len == 0) {
    return 1;
  }

  // first loop: we go through all elements of `arr1` (but we stop when we have less elements left than `arr2`'s len)
  for (size_t i = 0; i < arr1_len && i < arr2_len; i += 1) {
    // temporary flag, we just pretend that `arr2` is contained, and then we check for the opposite
    int eq = 1;

    // starting with the current position `i` inside `arr1`, we start checking if `arr2` is contained
    for (size_t j = 0; j < arr2_len; j += 1) {
      // if it's not contained, we break from this inner loop, and we keep searching through `arr1`
      if (arr1[i + j] != arr2[j]) {
          eq = 0;
          break;
      }
    }

    // in case `arr2` is effectively found, we return `1`
    if (eq == 1) {
      return 1;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

NOTE: "strings of integers" are called "arrays of integers" in C; a "string" is an "array of chars", instead.